# Searching cell array with regex

Tags: matlab

I often find myself trying to search cell arrays like I would want to search a database with a sql query. In this case, I've got a number of military bases (bases.shp)

`bases = shaperead('us-military-bases.shp')`

and then I want to filter down the shape file to get Air Force bases, something like `regexp({bases.FAC_NAME}','Air Force')`. But the output I get is the fairly cumbersome:

```
[]
[]
[ 4]
[]
[]
[ 9]
[]
```

I am sure filtering down cell arrays or shapefiles is pretty common and there have to be some good practices. Thanks for any insight.

I am also trying things like:

```
trif = arrayfun(@(x)regexp(x.FAC_NAME,'Griff','match'),af_bases)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given the output of `regexp` you can index back into the original cell array just by checking if each item in the resultant cell array is empty. You can do this using `cellfun` to apply a function to each cell.

To get an array of logicals, for non-empty items you can do:

```
base_strings = {bases.FAC_NAME}';

ind = ~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(base_strings, 'Air Force'))
```

Or more cleanly using an anonymous function:

```
ind = cellfun(@(x)( ~isempty(x) ), regexp(base_strings, 'Air Force'))
```

Then, to filter:

```
filtered = base_strings(ind);
```