# Matlab a more efficient solution to search for strings in a cell array

Tags: regex, arrays, string, matlab

I would like to search a vector of strings in two columns of a cell array of strings A  (300.000 x 7).

```
 string=[53716;59428;58221;679854].
```

Here below is the code:

```
y=arrayfun(@(x)~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(A(:,3:4),string(x))),1:numel(string),'uni',false);

y=cat(1,y{:});
```

This question is similar to [How to search for a string in cell array in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061344/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-cell-array-in-matlab) and this one [Searching cell array with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824442/searching-cell-array-with-regex)

However this solution takes hours. Does anyone know a more efficient way to perform the same operation?

Comment: What you have there is not a vector of strings. Oh, and instead of `cellfun(@isempty, ...)` use `cellfun('isempty', ...)`. It should run much faster.

Comment: Thank you but it is still very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing strings to doubles ("string" is a double array); is that what you want to do? If not, you could use `string_chars=arrayfun(@(x) sprintf('%d',string(x)),1:length(string),'uni',false);`

To avoid regexp, you could use strcmp:

```
result = zeros(size(A(:,3:4)));
for v=1:length(string_chars)
    result=result+v.*strcmp(A(:,3:4),string_chars(x)); % Should string be a cell here, btw?
end
```

I don't know if adding the results as I am doing here suits your use, but you can adapt as needed. This will set elements of result to correspond to each element of `string_chars`.

Comment: +1. If more speed is the goal, avoid Matlab's pathetically slow regex implementation especially for simple comparisons like this. And of course never be afraid of `for` loops.