# Simplest way to find out if at least one cell in a cell array matches a regular expression

Tags: regex, matlab, cell-array

I need to search a cell array and return a single boolean value indicating whether any cell matches a regular expression.

For example, suppose I want to find out if the cell array `strs` contains `foo` or `-foo` (case-insensitive).  The regular expression I need to pass to regexpi is `^-?foo$`.

Sample inputs:

`strs={'a','b'}` % result is 0

`strs={'a','foo'}` % result is 1

`strs={'a','-FOO'}` % result is 1

`strs={'a','food'}` % result is 0

I came up with the following solution based on [How can I implement wildcard at ismember function of matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18174133/44737) and [Searching cell array with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6824442/44737), but it seems like I should be able to simplify it:

```
~isempty(find(~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(strs, '^-?foo$'))))
```

The problem I have is that it looks rather cryptic for such a simple operation.  Is there a simpler, more human-readable expression I can use to achieve the same result?

Comment: I don't see it as cryptic. If you understand what `isempty`, `find` and `cellfun` do, it is pretty obvious

Comment: You could avoid the `find`, like so: `any(~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(strs, '-?foo')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NOTE*: The answer refers to the original regexp in the question: `'-?foo'`

You can avoid the `find`:

```
any(~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(strs, '-?foo')))
```

Another possibility: concatenate first all cells into a single string:

```
~isempty(regexpi([strs{:}], '-?foo'))
```

Note that you can remove the "-" sign in any of the above:

```
any(~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(strs, 'foo')))

~isempty(regexpi([strs{:}], 'foo'))
```

And that allows using `strfind` (with `lower`) instead of `regexpi`:

```
~isempty(strfind(lower([strs{:}]),'foo'))
```

Comment: I forgot about `any`!  I figured there had to be something at least a little simpler than wrapping it all in `~isempty(find())`.  Thanks.  Oops, I guess I goofed and my regex should have been `^-?foo$` so the concatenation won't work in my case...but maybe it'll be helpful for someone else.  Thanks again for the quick & thorough answer.